# How to make a table sortable by header angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting

im trying to make my table sortable by headers.

I tried using something called "smart-table" but that gave me some troubles as some of the headers contain spaces and special characters like "<" which made the parser give lots of errors.

I also tried http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ guide but couldnt get it to work. I made a file called sorttable.js and imported the script in the header of my html file and it didnt work:S.

So im wondering if anyone know of a good way to make this work?

Html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in table.cols">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in table.data">
            <td ng-repeat="col in table.cols">{{row[col]}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Data looks something like this:

```
table = {
    "data": [
        {"Name": "Bumbanday MCHP", "ANC 1 Coverage": 0, "BCG Coverage <1y":1},
        {"Name": "Bumban MCHPhgghfruin everythinggh", "ANC 1 Coverage": 0, "BCG Coverage <1y":1}
      ],

    "cols": [
      "Name",
      "ANC 1 Coverage",
      "BCG Coverage <1y"
      ]
}
```

Thanks:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had a lot of success with ng-table:

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table